# htaccess CORS issue between main domain and subdomain using my own API

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a main domain ygoprodeck.com and a subdomain db.ygoprodeck.com.

My main domain contains the following htaccess entry:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
   SetEnvIfNoCase Origin "https?://(www\.)?(ygoprodeck\.com|db\.ygoprodeck\.com)(:\d+)?$" ACAO=$0
   Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin %{ACAO}e env=ACAO
</IfModule>
```

I didn't create this myself as I needed htacess help when I initially set it up.

On my subdomain (db.ygoprodeck.com), I am hosting a public API in PHP that contains multiple endpoints and they have the following headers set:

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods:GET');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Authorization, X-Requested-With');
```

If I try access one of these endpoints on my main domain, I get a CORS issue:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://db.ygoprodeck.com/api/v7/archetypes.php' from origin 'https://ygoprodeck.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values '*, https://ygoprodeck.com', but only one is allowed.
```

Is there a way around this without potentially breaking my domain/subdomain htaccess rule? I'm really not great with htaccess so I'm worried about breaking something if I try doing tests. 
I know this is caused by having the header in my PHP file and having my htaccess rule, hence the issue. I do however need the header inside my PHP file due to external use of the API.

Edit Example:

I call `https://db.ygoprodeck.com/api/v7/archetypes.php` on ygoprodeck.com/testpage and I receive the error above. This is because the * PHP header is set in the API conflicts with my htaccess. Removing this will fix the issue, however it needs to remain as the API is also accessed externally as it's a public API.

Maybe something like this would work in PHP:

```
if(false == stripos($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], "www.ygoprodeck.com")){
  header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
}
```

Comment: Well your error message says what is wrong: **header contains multiple values '*, https://ygoprodeck.com', but only one is allowed.**

Comment: Yes, I am aware. I need the header set on my php API as it's used by external Devs however I don't want to break my htaccess for my main domain.

Comment: From your description, it isn’t clear to me, what problem actually needs fixing here? Please explain in what specific situation you want to allow access from `https://ygoprodeck.com` only, and in which ones _any_ origin should be allowed.

Comment: Hey CBroe, when I call the API from my main domain I get the error above. This is because the "*" header is set in my PHP file conflicting with my htaccess. Removing this would fix the issue, however it needs to remain there as it's a public API that is accessed externally so I'm not sure how to make both work?